# Why does the Log4J environment variable need both core and api JAR's?

Tags: java, import, log4j2

When installing Log4J, we need to have two variables in the system classpath :

```
log4j-api
log4j-core
```

The log4j-api variable looks like this :

**log4j-api** : `C:\apache_log4j_beta5\apache-log4j-2.0-beta5-bin\log4j-api-2.0-beta5.jar`

And the `log4j-core` variable looks like this :

log4j-core: `C:\apache_log4j_beta5\apache-log4j-2.0-beta5-bin\log4j-core-2.0-beta5.jar`

Both of these env. variables go into the overlapping `LOG4J_HOME` variable :

**LOG4J_HOME -** `%log4j-api%;%log4j-core%`

Why does it need both the api and core libraries(JAR files) though? When I import a class, I say :

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
```

So which of the above JAR's get searched for here? Is it core or api ? any tips appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`log4j-api`, as it's name says is an API. So basically it just contains interfaces that you can use to interface your code with the log4j framework. `log4j-core` is the implementation of this interface, so it contains actual code. It implements every interface in the API.

So basically when you import the `Logger` class, you import it from the API library. And when you call `LogManager.getLogger()` it first initializes itself in a static block, and it will try to search for valid implementations. And that's why you need the core library too.